# Laravel Undefined Variable. How to pass multiple variables from one or more controllers to view(s)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, laravel-8

I am trying to pass a variable from a controller to a view which is included in my main view. I tried it doing it in the following ways below and I get the `Undefined Variable` error.

Initially I tried creating a controller and tried passing the variable using the `compact()` to the view which I included in to my main view.

**MyController.php**

```
    public function example() {
        $example = example::all()->toArray();
        return view('front.exampleview.index', compact('example'));
    }
```

**exampleview/index.blade.php**

```
<div>
    @foreach($example as $item)
        <img src="{{ asset('uploads/example/').$item['image'] }}" alt="">
    @endforeach
</div>
```

As I did not find any luck with the above mentioned method, I tried working with a controller that was already there and figured since I am passing a variable with that controller I might as well use it. But no luck here either.

**ProductController.php**

```
    public function index() {
        $product = product::all()->toArray();
        return view('front.shop', compact('product'));
    }

    public function product(product $slug) {
        return view('front.product', compact('slug'));
    }

    public function example() {
        $example = example::all()->toArray();
        return view('front.exampleview.index', compact('example'));
    }
```

I tried changing the return target to my main view with both the ways mentioned above and still no luck.

Comment: use `dd($example)` at `index.blade.php` to see what u get

Comment: @Pradeep Undefined variable: example

Comment: can u show your view also?

Comment: Are you showing us the view `exampleview/index.blade.php` or `front/exampleview/index.blade.php` ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti front/exampleview/index.blade.php

Comment: @Pradeep the view is there as it is. All I did is include the `front/exampleview/index.blade.php` in my main view.

Answer (score 0):

your Code look okay , Can you try to change the variable name  form `$exemple` to `$tempexmple` actually in `compact()` it passing the object( exemple::  facade).
do same for `$product`.

if possible share the error message here.
thanks

Comment: This is the error message I get: `ErrorException
Undefined variable: example(View: D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\front\exampleview\index.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try that code,

**MyController.php**

```
public function example(){
        $example = example::all()->toArray();
        return view('front.exampleview.index', ['example' => $example]);
  }
```

**OR**

you can also try that

```
public function example(){
        $example = example::all()->toArray();
        return view('front.exampleview.index')->compact('example');
  }
```